# Regression Neural Network returning low range values for prediction

Tags: python, keras, regression

I am trying to predict a value that ranges from 3 to 7 with a regression nn model. I currently have 1000 samples with 1000 points each, corresponding to physiological data. However, predictions are always in the range of 5.6 to 5.9. I have tried to change the number of layers, adjust parameters etc.. but it only changes the basal value, not the range (i.e. predicts, for example, in the range of 6.6 to 6.9).

Here's the basic core of the algorithm (data is already normalized):

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_0, y_0, test_size=0.2, shuffle = False, stratify = None)
K.clear_session()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(1000,)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_error", optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

model.summary()
history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=30, epochs=10,verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
score = model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
print("Test score:", score)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your input is sorted, and I can see that you set `shuffle=False` in `train_test_split`. This means that validation values have never been seen by you neural network. And so it will not extrapolate during validation. Setting `shuffle=True` should work.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it did not work, still on the same range. Is the dataset too small?

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that the NN predicts the same range if your data is shuffled. Unless you have very few samples